# Android API to check if call is Active or On Hold

Tags: android

Is there an API function to check if a call is currently Active, or if has been put on Hold?

Assuming I have two connected calls, is there a way to check if each one is active, on-hold, or maybe they are connected in a conference call?

Answer (score 37):

Yes, you can check if a call is active over device or not:

```
public static boolean isCallActive(Context context){
   AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
   if(manager.getMode()==AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL){
         return true;
   }
   else{
       return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a nice idea. I just added a 2nd follow up question, because this only solves half my problem (which I guess wasn't stated very well)

Comment: I don't think this is advisable way to do so because audio manager can be used by other applications also to set different modes (like mode_normal or mode_in_call) for their own purposes .. in that way above code will not be useful.

Comment: This is not a sure indication that a phone call is active; but luckily, this method allows to find if a VOIP call is active, too.

Comment: MODE_IN_CALL - `In call audio mode. A telephony call is established.` // MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION - `In communication audio mode. An audio/video chat or VoIP call is established.` // AudioManager.setMode - `(...) In particular, the MODE_IN_CALL mode should only be used by the telephony application when it places a phone call, as it will cause signals from the radio layer to feed the platform mixer.`. So is MODE_IN_CALL not just perfect here? setMode says MODE_IN_CALL should be used only by the telephony app, so I guess Phone app. So all cool and no one else will use it! Or I didn't get it right?

Comment: Also, this doesn't work in call cases. If I have a call active and another waiting, I finish the call active and answer the one waiting, this won't say there was a period of time with no call active (after I finish the active one and before I answer the waiting one). It's always MODE_IN_CALL since the moment one call gets the phone to CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK until the phone goes to CALL_STATE_IDLE, no matter if I didn't answer the waiting call at all or not. It would help me deal with something if this worked on all cases. Seems it doesn't... One less idea haha.

Answer (score 6):

**This is proper way:**

1. Add a permission to manifest:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

2. Request permission from the user:

```java
private boolean runThisWhileStartingApp() {
  boolean hasPhonePermission = checkPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, "Explantation why the app needs this permission");
  if (!hasPhonePermission) {
    // user did not allow READ_PHONE_STATE permission
  }
}

private boolean checkPermission(final String permissionName, String reason) {
  if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MyActivity.this, permissionName) != android.content.pm.PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MyActivity.this, permissionName)) {
      AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this).create();
      alertDialog.setTitle(permissionName);
      alertDialog.setMessage(reason);
      alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
      alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
          new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              dialog.dismiss();
              ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MyActivity.this, new String[]{ permissionName }, 1000);
            }
          });
      alertDialog.show();
    } else {
      ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(InitActivity.this, new String[]{ permissionName }, 1000);
    }
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

3. And finally, check if device handles ongoing call anytime:

```java
TelecomManager tm = (TelecomManager) getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE);
boolean isInCall = tm.isInCall(); // true if there is an ongoing call in either a managed or self-managed ConnectionService, false otherwise
```

Documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/TelecomManager#isInCall()